# Space character as string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, whitespace

I have a function that checks the user input before it inserts into a database. It is something like this:

```php
function fix ($data) {
    if ((strlen($data) == 0) || (empty($data)) || ($data == "")) {
        echo "Please try again";
        die();
    } else {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Why does this function return true if the user inputs space characters?

Comment: Because a space character __is a character__.... `strlen(" ")` is greater than 0 (it has a length of 1); `empty(" ")` is false, it isn't empty, it contains a space; and `" " !== ""`, they're not the same

Comment: The usual idiomatic way is: `if (0 === strlen(trim($data))) { die('Please try again'); } else { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

A string containing `"    "` is NOT the same as an empty string. It has a length of 4 (4 spaces). It is also not the same as the empty string `""` because it has 4 characters in it. If you want to check if a string is empty or only whitespace, try this:

(see docs: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-space.php)

```
if (strlen($data) == 0 || ctype_space($data)) {
  //this is empty or all whitespace
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: how about strlen(trim($data)) ?

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with PHP and `false`y values

```
$x = ''; // empty string is false
```

vs

```
$x = ' ';
```

A space is a character, which means the string is NOT empty and therefore not false. You can fix this with

```
trim($x); // removes the space so we have an empty string
```

Answer (score 0):

In all three of your checks, a space will pass.

```
$string = ' ';
strlen($string) // == 1
empty($string) // == false
$string == '' // == false
```

What you should do it `trim` your string before your checks, as this removes superfluous whitespace

```
trim($string);
if (strlen($data) == 0 || empty($data) || $data == "") {
```

Comment: `trim($string)` won't actually modify the string. Try `$data = trim($data)`. This has the obvious downside of actually modifying the data, which may or may not be desireable.